# Link to Microsoft Open XML SDK tutorials

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

Anyone know any link to a good Microsoft Open XML tutorials?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the official place to learn about Open XML: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx.

You can just skim through all results in msdn.microsoft.com for Open XML SDK

Comment: This link is now dead.  The closest match I could find for SDK V2.5 is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Here are some other links to get your started:

1. http://openxmldeveloper.org/default.aspx

   - Not too active, but does get a decent amount of tutorials.
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2010/04/06/zeyad-rajabi-s-open-xml-sdk-blog-map.aspx

   - Microsoft program manager's blog for code snippets and tutorials.
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491088.aspx

   - More code snippets on how to perform certain tasks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an Open XML content list that has > 300 entries in it.  You can filter by a variety of keywords.

http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/open-xml-content-by-keyword.aspx

also

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/20/eric-white-s-blog-s-table-of-contents.aspx#Open_XML