# Beginner sample codes for the Open XML SDK?

Tags: ms-office, openxml, openxml-sdk

I recently started working on the Open XML SDK 2.0.

I would like to know if there is any better documentation (instead of open xml sdk2.0 itself) or any other resource to learn working with the Open XML SDK?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides everything on MSDN, the most well-known place to learn Open XML and the SDK is http://openxmldeveloper.org/.

Comment: there are even some good videos out there to start with http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/pdc2008/pc34

Comment: yeah, that's considered "MSDN". If you want a really good one on MSDN, check out Eric White's blog @ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/. He is really, really good with explaining Open XML and the SDK.

Comment: brian jone's  blog too is a good resource.http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/

Comment: In Nuget, now support OpenXML SDK 2.0. http://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenXmlSdk/ will be available for OpenXML SDK 2.5?

Answer (score 28):

For me, the best resource was the OpenXML Productivity Tool.  It is in the OpenXMLSDKTool.msi installation package.

This tool lets you open any existing word or excel document and browse a C# source code representation of the document.  It is a great way to learn how to perform some of the more complicated tasks.

Comment: Thanks Brian - i found this a zillion times more useful than the msdn docs, and blog posts which tried and failed to explain some simple tasks.

Comment: How detect programatically if OpenXML Productivity Tool is installed?. OpenXML Productivity Tool supports OpenXML SDK 2.0 or 2.5 ?

Comment: works on PowerPoint also.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2010/04/06/zeyad-rajabi-s-open-xml-sdk-blog-map.aspx) by some of the program managers for the Open XML SDK.  That particular link will take you to a roadmap of their blog which will link you to a bunch of examples.

Also, this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724204/link-to-microsoft-open-xml-sdk-tutorials) question adds some additional links.

Answer (score 3):

[Eric White](http://ericwhite.com/blog/introduction-to-open-xml-expanded/) has a great tutorial on Open XML at his blog.

Answer (score 2):

There is a surprisingly useful information is an unexpected place: Inside the program "XML SDK Productivity Tool"

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

Comment: You should consider ClosedXML as well. It is much easier to use. It was recommended to me by Eric White himself.

Comment: Another tool that deserves consideration is ClosedXML. It is MUCH easier to use. It was recommended to me by Eric White himself.   https://closedxml.codeplex.com/