# Export SQL query result to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, sql-server-2008

When I click a button I want to export data returned from a stored procedure to an Excel file using Asp.Net C# And Sql Server?

Comment: Do you have to use asp.net and c#? you can load the data on excel connected direct to sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use COM Interop to create a new excel sheet: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx
Read values from your database, then create the excelsheet.

You could also think about using the CSV format.
You can easely write a ';' seperated csv file which can be imported in excel
It depends on what your reason is to store in excel format.

Answer (score 1):

just put your output as a table and add

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + filName+ ".xls");
```

Comment: i need but the data of ( SqlDataReader ) to Excel file

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using a SDK like the OpenXMLSDK which is not specific to `Microsoft`, but can generate the documents in any format that can be opened across different operating systems and platforms.

For more details, the pointers are as follows,

1. [Beginner sample codes for the Open XML SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343123/beginner-sample-codes-for-the-open-xml-sdk)
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371203/Creating-basic-Excel-workbook-with-Open-XML
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478153.aspx

This is used in many products and IMHO, a professional way to export data from applications.

Comment: i need but the data of ( SqlDataReader ) to Excel file